# The proper and easiest way of doing an integral with derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have this integral:

$$\int{\sec^3x\,\mathrm dx}$$

I don't understand how I would solve this. Google and YouTube videos don't help me understand much, other than just giving the answer.

Is it possible to explain step-by-step how this would be solved, assuming that this is the first time I'm seeing it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: The existence of that wiki page is absurd. Using by parts is obvious! Why on earth is the antiderivative of $\sec^3 x$ so very important? `It seems to be the only integral with its own page on wikipedia o_O

Comment: @Nick, not quite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function

Comment: @KajHansen: Well, there are only two pages of the like. Upon further dwelling into its citations, I find that these integrals have certain historical significance but the truth is that it isn't anymore historically significant than a bunch of other common antiderivatives. Also, these aren't even nearly as hard to do as certain simple looking integrals that I've come across. Should they not deserve pages of their own too?

Answer (score 8):

$$\int \sec^3(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
Integrate by parts, with

$$dv=\sec^2(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

$$v=\tan(x)$$

$$u=\sec(x)$$

$$du=\sec(x)\tan(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Obtaining

$$
\begin{align}
\int \sec^3(x)\,\mathrm dx &= \sec(x)\tan(x)-\int \sec(x)\tan^2(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\sec(x)\tan(x)-\int \sec(x)\left(\sec^2(x)-1\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\sec(x)\tan(x)-\int \left( \sec^3(x)-\sec(x) \right)\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}\
$$

$$\int \sec^3(x) \, \mathrm dx = \sec(x)\tan(x)-\int \sec^3(x)\,\mathrm dx + \int \sec(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Adding $\int \sec^3(x)\,\mathrm dx$ to both sides yields

$$2\int \sec^3(x)\,\mathrm dx =\sec(x)\tan(x) + \log\Big|\sec(x)+\tan(x)\Big|$$

Dividing by $2$ gives

$$\int \sec^3(x)\,\mathrm dx= \dfrac{\sec(x)\tan(x)+\log\Big|\sec(x)+\tan(x)\Big|}{2} + \mathcal C$$

Comment: @Mehrdad: This issue has been fixed.

Comment: **Note::** The answer can also be expressed as:
$$\int \sec^3 \theta \,\mathrm d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\sec \theta \tan \theta + \ln{\sqrt{\sec \theta + \tan \theta}} + \mathcal C$$

Comment: @Nick: You need an absolute value sign under the square root.